# URL in string interpolation not clickable : Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a variable which contains text as well as a URL, When I am putting that variable within string interpolation the link within anchor tag is showing as plain text.

**Question :** how I can make the url clickable within string interpolation.

**Component.ts**

```
public textWithURL : string = 'Google - <a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>';
```

**Component.HTML**

```
<div>
   <p>{{ textWithURL }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That will be because Angular doesn't trust the contents of `textWithURL`, this is done to try and prevent XSS attacks!

Comment: @phuzi, Awesome and thank you. It is working